# PHPexcel html to excel with images

Tags: php, html, excel

I write code like this:

```
        require_once(VENDOR . 'phpexcel/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
        $objPHPExcel = new \PHPExcel();
        $xlsxname = WWW_ROOT.'excelexport/kontrahent-'.$q->id_kontrahent.'.xlsx';

        $table = '<table>'.$_POST['print'].'</table>';
        // print_r($_POST);


$file = WWW_ROOT.'NowExcelExport.html';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = $table;
file_put_contents($file, $current);



        $filename = 'excelexport/kontrahent-'.$q->id_kontrahent.'.xls';
        // $table = $_POST['table'];

        ini_set('zlib.output_compression','Off'); 
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        //the folowing two lines make sure it is saved as a xls file
        header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);

        $objReader = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('HTML');
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($file);

        $objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');



        exit;
```

Okey, now I input to this code, a html code. This code have images .png/.jpg etc. Export works fine but in my excel files not showing images. Do you have any idea how I can export images?

Comment: The problem is that the HTML Reader won't read the images, there is no code in the Reader to do that..... why are you saving your markup to a file as html and then loading it again from that file? Why can't you build the spreadsheet directly as a PHPExcel object?

Comment: I must generate html firstly because my client server allow only 30sec execute time, and I generate a lot of data, some Times this must calculate data from 4place on MySQL. My idea is simple, I download data via jquery to html table (data is downoladed by parts ) and in next step send data via form post. This method work but send images via post  (img src......) not show in Excel :(

Comment: They won't show in the generated Excel, because (as I said previously) the HTML Reader won't read the images.... if you want the images, then you'll have to add them directly to the PHPExcel object.... But you're still using a convoluted method that's likely to take longer than simply building the PHPExcel object in the first place